# Is there anything called as ‘infinite consciousness’?

Tags: consciousness

We understand what is meant by infinite space. No matter in which direction we go we will never find end of space... Similarly can we define what is infinite consciousness? ( I hope meaning of consciousness is clear )

Comment: Can we define it or does it exist? Imagine that *space* is a "sentient being"; then if infinite, it will be an "infinite consciousness". Having said that, do you think that we have made some real progress?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I don’t think so ...we have not made any progress on the question of consciousness....but roughly it translates into volition , perception , feelings etc

Comment: It is something attributed to God or ["universal mind"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_mind) of New Thought movement in contrast to "finite" human consciousness. "*On the one hand our finitude prevents us from being able to think of anything, including the whole of reality, as truly infinite. On the other hand it also prevents us from being able to think of anything finite – anything to that extent within our grasp – as the whole of reality.*" [Routledge, Human finitude](https://www.rep.routledge.com/articles/thematic/infinity/v-1/sections/human-finitude).

Comment: "I hope meaning of consciousness is clear" i am afraid it is not at all.

Comment: @armand It is quite disturbing that such a simple thing can not defined properly... my guess is it means knowledge...things without consciousness have no knowledge of anything...

Comment: Then infinite knowledge would be omniscience, knowing everything there is to know, considering there is an infinity of things to know, which is not a far fetch. Remains the problem of what substrate would store this knowledge, since as far as we know there is no knowledge without a material substrate.

Comment: I remember there was an ancient Greek philosopher once had an analogy of what is "conscious of something" and what is "knowing something", the former is like a flat palm which can be easily morphed into various shapes from outside influences, while the latter is like a fist which is much more stable. So if this is true, I'd rather want a fist than a thousand or even infinite consciousness...

Comment: Infinitism in epistemology might be along the lines of what the OP is after: consciousness (as knowledge) that goes on forever. https://iep.utm.edu/inf-epis/ is a good overview.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Although you have used the term 'Infinite Consciousness', it is nothing but Pure Consciousness. I am saying so because Pure Consciousness is Infinite Consciousness.

Please don't think that this is something related to some religion. If you didn't like the term in Sanskrit, you are free to use it as Pure Consciousness.

You may try to understand this idea using synonyms of 'infinite'.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaitanya_(consciousness)

Let me quote this part of the statement of yours -- "...No matter in which direction we go we will never find end of space."

You can think of  'us' while dealing subjects like mathematics, physics etc.; no problem. But when you think only of pure consciousness, you have to forget about plurality.

So I shall change your statement like this -- "...No matter in which direction I go I will never find end of space."

You won't find any difference in these two ideas if you think that 'I' is body related.  One can understand this idea only when one is free from the misconception about 'I'.

Again, the terms, ‘direction’ and 'go' are meaningless where there is no ‘time’. [It is the one,  without a second.](https://www.dailypioneer.com/2019/state-editions/brahman--the-absolute-truth.html#:%7E:text=He%20is%20the%20One%2C%20without,manifestation%20in%20time%20and%20space.)

'Pure/Infinite consciousness' cannot be defined.